# Challenge with curve ed25519

Tags: elliptic-curves, ed25519

Recently a friend of mine showed me a "puzzle" he created with curve ed25519

It is based on adding and multiplying points on the curve

You supply three arguments to the program

```
The 'public key'
The 'private key'
additional data
```

He considers the puzzle as solved if the following 'equation' applies:

static-point = cdaaf6715f5aace083b25b3b2f621ebacc5e7f25463e1e51100cc16677bb158a

hash = sha512(public key + data)[:32] // first 32 bytes

private key * ed25519 base point == ed25519addpoint(ed25519scalarmult(hash * public key), static point)

It can be represented with the following python code with the usage of nacl cryptography library:

```
import nacl.bindings
import hashlib

def sha512(data):
    h = hashlib.sha512()
    h.update(data)
    res = h.digest()
    return res

data = "additional data in hex".decode("hex")
privkey = "private key in hex".decode("hex")
pubkey = "public key in hex".decode("hex")
static = "cdaaf6715f5aace083b25b3b2f621ebacc5e7f25463e1e51100cc16677bb158a".decode("hex")

pprim = sha512(pubkey + data)
pprim = pprim[:32]

x = nacl.bindings.crypto_scalarmult_ed25519_base(privkey)
y = nacl.bindings.crypto_core_ed25519_add(nacl.bindings.crypto_scalarmult_ed25519(pprim, pubkey), static)

if x == y:
    print "Congratulations, puzzle solved!"
else:
    print "Not really"
```

He claims that he found multiple solutions to this problem. My question is: is this really solvable (and if yes, how?) or is he only trying to trick me into trying to solve an unsolvable problem.

From my cryptographic knowledge of ed25519 curve you cannot solve this from both ways:

- if you supply any value as the private key you could subtract the static point and then try to find values of pprim and public key - if it is solvable this is the way I tried to solve it
- compute the hash of public key and data and then try to find the value of private key

Both of this ways are impossible for me, because either solution is equal to finding private key from public (d from having P = d*G) on ed25519 which, from my knowledge is impossible.

Comment: Duplicate of https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/106900/edwards-curve-ed25519-puzzle

Comment: @knaccc: well spotted. I closed the [other Q](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/106900/555) as duplicate of this one, since we have an answer here, and the question contains more of the original problem (likely a CTF): here it looks like we can't change `static`, when it looks like we could in the other Q. To the OP: I guess you lost access to your former account deneth0r9. Merging these is possible, but unfortunately is complex.

Comment: Is the actual puzzle finding what hex strings must be put instead of `"additional data in hex"`, `"private key in hex"` and `"public key in hex"` in order to reach the _Congratulations_ branch? This looks like a CTF (which is bordeline if at all on-topic), and it would help (towards being on-topic, and resolution) to write it in mathematical notation rather than Python. Possible hint: have you considered deliberately making `pubkey` such that `pprim`×`pubkey` is one of few remarkable points regardless of the haphazard construction of pprim ?

Answer (score 1):

*Reading another closed question I must add cases to this answer. The question, however, still provide insufficient details.*

**CASE 1: If *static point* is always constant** (the one you gave in question) **no matter what private key and data value you choose**

It is impossible. Let,

$x_p$ be private key, public key be $x_{pu}$, $s_{pu}$ be static point and the key corresponding to static point be $s_p$, and let $e$ be hash bytes, and let $d$ is data.

Notaions: $*$ sigify multiplication as if $2*2=4$, $+$ sinify addition as if $2+6=8$ $.$ signify scalar multiplication and $+'$ signify point addition.

Now:

$x_p.G=(e.x_{pu})+'(s_p.G)$

$x_p.G=(e*x_{p}.G)+'(s_p.G)$

$x_p.G=(e*x_{p}+s_p).G$

$x_p = e*x_p + s_p$

Since, all opertaions in elliptic curves are performed modulo $n$ the above holds true iff:

$x_p \equiv e*x_p + s_p \mod{n}$

$x_p - s_p \equiv e*x_p \mod{n}$

$1 - (s_p*(x_p)^{-1}) \equiv e \mod{n}$ ...(i)

We know that hash functions are always one way so in order to produce same output, input must be same.

We also know that $e = H (x_p || d)$ where $H$ is the hash function.

Analysing (i) we can conclude:

*for a given $x_p$ there will be only one hash $e$*

But this contradict the fact that our hash function $e = H (x_p || d)$ depends on two variables namely $x_p$ and $d$.

In other words the output of hash is independent of variables which means collisions which means that the hash function is itself broken.

Recall that your friend is talking about SHA512. Which means he has broken one of the most secure hashing algorithm. Volla.

**CASE 2: If choice of *static point* depends on the private key value and data**

It is possible. Because in that case you need to define $s_{pu}$ as $(1-e).x_{pu}$. Because:

$s_p = (1-e)*x_p$ substituting this in

$x_p = e*x_p + s_p$

$x_p = e*x_p + x_p - e*x_p$

$x_p = x_p$

Hence LHS = RHS

But if case 2 is your case then there is nothing like **puzzle** in your question.

Comment: Possible hint [updated to match the extended answer, and clarify]: Could there be a loophole in the CASE 1 argument where it is assumed that $x_{pu}$ (that is `pubkey`) can be written as $x_p.G$? Independently, this arguments holds if `static` was random, which is unclear in the Q. If we are allowed to choose `static`, it's easy to do so as a function of `data`, `privkey`, `pubkey` to satisfy the requirement. Assuming the problem was generated in this way with guessable `data` (e.g. empty), `privkey` (e.g.equivalent to integer 2) and `pubkey` (e.g. equivalent to $3.G$), then it can be solved.

Comment: @fgrieu I am unable to understand your hint, what does 'loophole' means?

Comment: [updated to match the extended answer] A loophole is a mean of escape, here of the conclusion in CASE 1 (I hope my usage is correct; I'm not a native English speaker either). I mean, if it was mathematically incorrect that for any point $x_{pu}$ of the curve (as limited by the possibility of applying the code fragments shown without causing an exception), it can be found integers $x_{p}$ with $x_p.G=x_{pu}$, the argument developed in CASE 1 would be wrong (beside not stating as hypothesis that `static` is arbitrary). This suggests an unexplored path, which may not lead to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I find the thought process to try tackle the question representative of the right state of mind for attacks on implementations, thus interesting even though the question is likely a CTF (which is why I wouldn't fully answer if I had solved the puzzle; I have not).

###### Notation from the [Ed25519 paper](https://ed25519.cr.yp.to/ed25519-20110926.pdf)

Let $q=2^{255}-19$. Let $d=−121665/121666\in\mathbb F_q$. Let
$$E=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb F_q\times\mathbb F_q:\;-x^2+y^2=1+dx^2y^2\}$$
Define addition on $E$ as $(x_1,y_1)+(x_2,y_2)=(\frac{x_1\,y_2+x_2\,y_1}{1+d\,x_1 x_2\,y_1\,y_2},\frac{y_1\,y_2-x_1\,x_2}{1-d\,x_1\,x_2\,y_1\,y_2})$.

Let $B$ be the unique $(x,4/5)\in E$ for which $x\bmod 2=0$ (where $0\le x<q$).

$(E,+)$ is an Elliptic Curve group of order $8\,\ell\gtrsim q$, with $B$ of prime order $\ell$.

Any $P\in E$ has a unique 32-byte representation as bytestring noted $\underline P$. But only a little above $\frac 1 2$ of 32-byte bytestrings represent an element of $E$.

###### The question's problem

Note the question's variables as follows. All are bytestrings, and I assume all except perhaps `data` are 32-byte:

| `data` | `privkey` | `pubkey` | `static` | `pprim` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $D$ | $R$ | $U$ | $S$ | $P$ |

$P$ is constructed by a pseudorandom function of $D$ and $U$ built from SHA-512. I assume $R$ and $P$ are assimilated to integers $r$ and $p$ in $[0,2^{256})$ per some convention that I won't dive into, built into `crypto_scalarmult_ed25519_base` and `crypto_scalarmult_ed25519`.

Broadly, we are given $S$ that Google finds only in the question, and asked $D$, $R$, $U$ with
$$r\cdot B=\bigl(p\cdot U\bigr)+S$$
where $\cdot$ and $+$ are scalar multiplication and addition for the elliptic curve group $E$. This however is a simplification assimilating bytestrings $U$ and $S$ to points on $E$ with these representations, and leaves aside:

- Our ability to supply $U$ (aka `pubkey`) that's not among the 32-byte bytestrings that represent an element of $E$.
- The lack of assurance that the value of $S$ (aka `static`) in the question is among the 32-byte bytestrings that represent an element of $E$.

Possible hint: explore what adding $S$ with `crypto_core_ed25519_add` actually does.

Another possible hint: explore the ways to make $U$ (the representation of) some element of $E$ such that $p\cdot U$ would be noteworthy despite the hapazardness of $p$.